# How to show a dropdown without spinner?

Tags: android, kotlin

Hy,

I have a problem, and I can't figure out how to fix it.

So first of all, I used TextInputLayout with AutoCompleteText view, to show a drow down style, and it works well, but when I rotate the screen or couse configuration change like dark mode/light mode switch, the autcompleteTextView doesn't show the dropdown. I know it is an open issue, but I didn't find a working solution.

I tired setFreezesText = false, but it worked when I rotate the screen, and in on configuration change, any other case it didn't work.

```
layout:
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:id="@+id/opportunity_recording_hr_person_auto_complete_container"
                        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:hint="@string/responsible_hr_person_label">

                        <com.google.android.material.textfield.MaterialAutoCompleteTextView
                            android:id="@+id/opportunity_recording_hr_person_auto_complete_content"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

fragment:
    override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
        
        binding.opportunityRecordingHrPersonAutoCompleteContent.freezesText = false
    }
```

So after that, I changed this, to simple AutoCompleteTextView, and if it gets focus, I show the dropdown list, but unfortunately, it doesn't work, because when configuration changes happen I get this error: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

```
layout:
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/name_of_project_label"
                        android:labelFor="@+id/opportunity_recording_customer_auto_complete_content"/>
                    <AutoCompleteTextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/opportunity_recording_customer_auto_complete_content"
                        android:inputType="text"/>

fragment:
  // I call this on onCiewCreated()
    private fun initListeners() {
        binding.opportunityRecordingCustomerAutoCompleteContent.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, isFocused ->
            if (isFocused)
                binding.opportunityRecordingCustomerAutoCompleteContent.showDropDown()
        }
}
```

Is there any way to fix one of the problems at least?

Comment: Maybe you can try Popup Menu?

Comment: I thought about it, but it be will a lot of refact, so will do it, when there is no any other options.